# How to use request python 3 to login to website , then scrape data from that website

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

How to determine the request is get or post and how to know the parsed parameters ?

Comment: Take a look at the form itself and see how it is passing the form data.

Comment: Try logging in manually, and look at the HTTP request in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Are you using selenium to automate this task?

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish yes i use selenium for this is task

Comment: @Ahmed there are many links how to determine the correct one to choose

Comment: Do you use selenium often? I've used it to login to a page and scrape data and haven't had to use it to find out whether get or post is being passed. So are you able to send keys with selenium to the site?

Comment: @ Kamikaze_goldfish Yes i used that but this is low performance when there are many steps or logic in the app so , i want to do all that in the backend using requests without using selenium

Comment: Notice that you can setup login at setUpClass so that it is done once per test set. But if you want to get rid of doing login via selenium then you can try with requests.